# Как упаковать риг в base fk?

Tags: blender

У меня есть сложный риг.
И я хочу упаковать его в базовый fk риг
Примерно как здесь [video](https://youtu.be/pAhbO7U1ID8?t=290)

Как я могу это сделать? Может ли кто нибудь дать туториал по этой теме или просто объяснить мне сейчас?
Я еще не разу не работал с код в блендере поэтому можете объяснить как можно проще.
Или просто дайте аддон который упакует риг за меня.

Answer (score 0):

На видео показывается аддон rigify. Он идет вместе с блендером, его нужно просто активировать в настройках на вкладке аддоны